# Javascript in Razor View not activated

Tags: javascript, razor, view

I am trying to use some Javascript from a Razor View page, but it is never activated and cannot figure out why. Any help will be highly appreciated!

*Note: The View uses a shared layout that loads jQuery & Bootstrap for all views.*

Here is my latest Razor View code, but I have tried even more methods to activate the **textSubmit()** function, such as using the button onclock() tag, the form onsubmit() event, etc. and NOTHING works!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        textSubmit();
    });


    function textSubmit() {
        alert("You CLICKED!");
    }

</script>



<div id="workarea">
    <div id="emptylog"></div>

    <div id="chatbox">
        <form id="inputForm" role="form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputBox">Say something:</label>
                <input name="inputBox" id="inputBox" type="text" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script block is being parsed and evaluated before the DOM is done being parsed, so `$("#submit")` is finding no element with that id to attach the click event to.

Put your script inside jQuery's `ready` function and it will execute "as soon as the page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate" ( https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#submit").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    textSubmit();
  });

  function textSubmit() {
    alert("You CLICKED!");
  }
})
```

Comment: That you mlibby. It still does not work. The click() even is NOT FIRED. :-(

Comment: I checked this code and it works as a snippet. Are you getting any errors on your developer console in the web browser? Maybe your actual code has a typo? Did you do a full refresh of the page in the browser?